# How can I add a Free Gift product block on onestepcheckout page

Tags: magento

We are using onestepcheck and free gift extension of Mage world.
 Free Gift option is showing well on cart page[image: you can see here]

Now the problem is that I want exactly the same free Gift option on onestepcheckout [image: like that].
How can I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imran, i can guide you where to start.

in your app/code/design/frontend/your_theme/freegiftextension/ there must be a file for cart page, that must be overriding the default magento cart.phtml

Check the file and copy the code that shows the free gift selection as shown in screenshot above.

then you need to create onestepcheckout template and use the same code copied above, with some tweaks ofcourse.

Also you need to create model and controller for the above created action.. that will do the same as it was doing on the cart page action.

Hope this gives you things to start with.

Comment: Hi skv thank you reply back.will you please add me over skype my id = imran_tahir1
   I am ready to pay you for your time. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your support skv. it helps a lot :).

Comment: Thanks Imran, look forward to hear from you again.